# How to delete products but not orders associated with that product in Laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I would like a seller to be able to delete/edit a product he listed. But if that product has been ordered by customer, i would like the order to stay the same and not change. How can i accomplish this?

Right now when i update/delete it affects the orders submitted earlier.
This is how i delete products right now.

```
public function destroy($id) 
{ 
    $userId = Auth::user()->id; 
    $deleteData=product::where('seller_id', $userId)->findOrFail($id); 
    $deleteData->delete(); 

    return redirect()->back(); 
}
```

Order.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'seller_id');
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('quantity','total','Subtotal');
}

public function orderItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\OrderProduct');
}
```

Edit:

```
Controller for seller orders

// Seller Orders 
 public function viewOrders(User $user)
 {
 //$seller = Auth::user();
 $totals = OrderProduct::select("seller_id", DB::Raw("SUM(Subtotal) AS  total"), 'order_id')
 ->where('seller_id', '=',  \Auth::user()->id)
 ->groupBy('seller_id')
 ->groupBy('order_id')
 ->get();


 $orders = Order::whereHas('orderItems.product', function ($query) {
    $query->where('seller_id', '=',  \Auth::user()->id);
 })->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->withTrashed()->get();
 return view('orders', ['orders'=> $orders, 'total'=> $totals] );
 }
```

Seller blade template

```
@foreach ($order->orderItems as $item)
@if($item->product->user_id == Auth::user()->id)

   <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
   <td>{{ $item->price }}</td>
@else
  @endif
 @endforeach
```

OrderProduct.php

```
 class OrderProduct extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;
protected $table = 'order_product';
protected $fillable = ['order_id', 'seller_id','product_id', 'quantity','Subtotal','total','name','price'];


public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend not deleting the products, since you'll lose that relationship. Or at least, don't do a hard delete. You can use [soft deleting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#soft-deleting), so that they still exist in the database, but are hidden unless you specifically look for trashed items.

Comment: @aynber thanks for your answer. How about editing the product, how would that work?

Comment: The issue with linking the product directly to the order is that if the product is edited, historical orders get out of whack. I generally snap-shot the product onto the order (well a separate table `order_products`), with `product_name`, `product_price`, etc. so that editing/deleting doesn't mess with it. It's still linked by `id`, but loosely; it prefers the snapshotted values over the live ones.

Comment: @TimLewis should i move price, names of products and others to orders_products table if i understand you correctly?

Comment: @TimLewis what does that snap-shot means?

Comment: Snapshotting in this instance means copying the product information and saving it to a separate table (`orders_products`) when the order is created. This assumes orders can have multiple products. But that way, when the product is edited, the data on `orders_products` isn't updated, so you don't run into issues. This is all a little broad, and kinda requires the initial project to be setup with that in mind, so I probably can't provide an actual answer to this question; just guidelines that I use when developing eCommerce systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [`SoftDeletes`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scout#soft-deleting)trait to your product model.

To retrieve the products including those which have been removed, use this:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OrderProduct extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'order_product';
    protected $fillable = ['order_id', 'seller_id','product_id', 'quantity','Subtotal','total'];


    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product')->withTrashed();
    }

}
```

If you don't want to show the removed products, you can add a `->whereNull('p.deleted_at')` to the function where you retrieve your products:

```php
$products = DB::table('recommends AS r')
            ->leftJoin('products AS p', 'r.product_id', '=', 'p.id')
            ->join('products_photos AS pp', 'pp.product_id', '=', 'p.id')
            ->whereNull('p.deleted_at')
            ->select('p.id', 'p.pro_name', 'filename', 'p.pro_price', 'pro_info', DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS total'))
            ->groupBy('p.id', 'p.pro_name', 'filename', 'p.pro_price', 'pro_info')
            ->orderby('total', 'DESC')
            ->take(4);
```

It should solve your issues.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried both ways (using soft delete and creating order product table ) , if I edit the product  both sides buyer and seller are not affected but if I delete product only seller orders get deleted but buyer orders remain @Mateus Junges

Comment: How do your `seller oders` table looks like? @joh

Comment: Do you mean orders table or order_product table? @Mateus Junges

Comment: I mean the table where you save the seller orders, that you tell me that got deleted after deleting a product.

Comment: You have seller orders and customer orders, right? Did you tried to create a `order_products` table for each one?

Comment: Yes, I have seller orders and customer orders and also I have created `order_products table` @Mateus

Comment: I just have only one `order_products table` @Mateus Junges

Comment: Wouldn't it solve your problem if you create a table for `seller orders` and another one for `custmoer orders`?

Comment: it hasn't solve the problem in seller orders, if i delete  products also deletes the order  and also like I said I have only one `order_product table` @Mateus

Comment: When I delete the product it also deletes the `product_id` in `order_product` table @Mateus Junges

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196293/discussion-between-mateus-junges-and-joh).